# Using Meteor + Vue + D3, where should I put the d3 code?

Tags: meteor, d3.js, vue.js

I do not use Blaze (no template helpers) but Vue.js.

Is there a hook for putting the d3 code (not shure which one to use)?

Where should it be?

Answer (score 2):

D3 must be in Vue components. 
I would use [this](https://github.com/jaredreich/vue-d3)

Comment: Thanks, but I already use this package, the idea is about where should I put my code (reactive part, not the graph init) In a watch, in on tick, How should I call it for the first display?